# Detect Mouse Over on Image inside DatagridviewCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a custom DataGridView column which hosts both an image and text by deriving from the DataGridViewTextBoxCell class.

I would like to be able to detect when the mouse cursor is over only the image portion of the cell.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfMHw.jpg]

I tried creating a Rectangle object for each cell which gets set to the boundaries of the image in the Paint() method and determining whether the cursor location is contained in the boundary rectangle in the OnMouseMove() handler but this didn't work.

```
  protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds,
        Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState,
        object value, object formattedValue, string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        // Paint the base content
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState,
           value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
           advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        if (this.Image != null)
        {
            imgBoundsRect = new Rectangle(cellBounds.Location, this.Image.Size);
            // Draw the image clipped to the cell.
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsContainer container = graphics.BeginContainer();

            graphics.SetClip(cellBounds);
            graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(this.Image, cellBounds);

            graphics.EndContainer(container);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Location);
        if (imgBoundsRect.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            this.ToolTipText = "View Doc";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question but as it works for a `DataGridViewImageCell` I decided to leave it as a reference.

Your code looks pretty similar. Make sure to keep the `Location` of the `imgBoundsRect` at `(0,0)` just like the mouse coordinates in the `CellMouseMove`!

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    DataGridViewImageCell iCell = 
                     dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewImageCell;

    Text = "MISS";
    if (iCell != null)
    {
        Image img = iCell.FormattedValue as Image;
        Rectangle irect = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
        Point relLoc = e.Location;
        if (irect.Contains(relLoc)) Text = "HIT";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried incorporating this into the program I'm working on but since my cell contains both an image and text and derives from DataGridViewTextBoxCell I am having trouble determining whether it's the text or image portion of the cell that my cursor is on.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But that is what you are doing, right? The question is: Is the Rectangle `imgBoundsRect` correct ?

Comment: I just implemented a solution which uses both mine and your ideas and now it works.  I used your suggestion of setting the rect coordinates to 0, 0 and moved that rect.contains code into the OnMouseMove event handler of the custom class.  Thanks!